# Is it OK to copy an entire article as an answer to a question for archival purposes?

Tags: discussion, attribution

The title is clear, I think. I'd like to know whether or not this is acceptable, so long as the article provider allows it.

Comment: I've seen this done in a very popular answer about JS Closures.

Comment: It is absolutely unethical and not allowed.  Please flag the answer, select "Other" as the reason, and let the mod team know that the answer is plagiarized.  Please include a link to the original content.

Comment: Please link to the relevant answer. On an unrelated note "all in the title" type question-bodies are kind of annoying.

Comment: It is not unethical if the article provider allows it.

Answer (score 3):

If the copyright holder allows it (e.g. you are the copyright holder), that's certainly ok, provided:

- It all is relevant to the question (trimm and change as neccessary).
- If appropriate (e.g. the article is quite long and in-depth), provide an executive summary too.
- Use proper quotation with attribution (we have hyperlinks).
- Attribute and be up-front about this being a legit copy even if the copyright holder waives this requirement, we hate plagiarism.

If you ask the question in order to save that article, make sure it is an on-topic, high-quality question, irrespective of your laudable goal of preserving said stellar article.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, It's okay to quote an article so long as you

- Only include the relevant parts of the article
- Also include a description of what's at the article, and why the OP might be interested in it
- Include a link to the article, or otherwise attribute it
- Format the quote as a quote.

fortunately, markdown has a way to signify quotes.  Just put a > at the beginning of each line and it will appear in a quotation block.  There's also a quotation marks symbol in the text editor that you can use to format a block of text as a quote

> this is a quote block

Comment: I don't think you're answering exactly the question OP is asking. The title says "**full** article", and I believe it means taking the entire contents of an article and hosting it on SO as a precaution against it disappearing from the web.

Comment: Nice 180° change.

Comment: I should specify further, I had little time when writing the question yesterday. I meant, at least, a 95% of an article that is extremely relevant to a good question.