# Answers referencing Articles Written By Me

Tags: discussion, answers, external-links

I recently [posted an answer to an old question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28659677/2182928) about Knuth's formal definition of an algorithm - The Art of Computer Programming v1. The content of the answer is essentially copy pasted from an article I wrote recently on my (attempt at a) blog.

I've seen people copy-paste content directly from other pages before and as long as full disclosure is given that seems to be fine, and [this question/answers seems to confirm that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258414/is-it-ok-to-copy-an-entire-article-as-an-answer-to-a-question-for-archival-purpo/258416#258416). But, because the article is **mine**, could this be seen as self-promotion/spam?

If this ***is*** okay, is there anything I need to be careful of when doing this in the future? I don't want to fall foul of any potential issues, and I certainly don't want to be seen as self-promoting.

Comment: I fixed "Kunth" for you :)

Comment: It's self promotion if you just posted the answer in order to have another link to your blog. I don't assume so, but it may that your blog post is not a 100% applicable to the question and therefore explained too much (maybe judging by the length) or not enough. Then I would prefer a specific, just for this purpose, written answer. But otherwise, why not. No need to say the same things in different words over and over again.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> But, because the article is my own, could this be seen as self-promotion/spam?

It *could* be. The key to it not being seen as such is indeed full disclosure.

That it is an *excerpt* from the source helps as well - a full copy/paste or just a link would be seen as bad, for instance.

If, however, it was discovered that *most* posts by a person had such links, the community tends to be very vocally against it - that does appear to be an account that is only used for self promotion (not saying this is the case here, just giving an example).

---

I personally don't see anything wrong here - not with an occasional link to a highly relevant blog by the answer OP (so long as the question gets a full answer on the site).

Comment: So, would I be correct in assuming that I should do this only very infrequently, with full disclosure, and makes sure that all content I quote is absolutely relevant?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Answers should always fully answer the question, with links being auxiliary at best, anyways. When linking to your own content - always fully disclose that. And do that in a low frequency (i.e. don't only answer questions that allow you to link to your content...).

Comment: OTOH if you fail to link to your blog, but copy verbatim, (and use a different name/avatar on SO), then your post could be flagged as being plagiarized ;)

Comment: Thanks. I've made some amendments to the answer such that it covers **all** points that they wanted answered in the OP, and have made some clarifications about the source of the text.